# iOS Device doesn't recognise MessageUI

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

While building the in-app Mail ViewController `MFMailComposeViewController` I've tried to check if it works on my iPhone. It doesn't.

I get the error: `No such module 'MessageUI'` on the line `import MessageUI`.
I only get this when I'm trying to do it on my phone. It 100% works on the simulator.
I've got a couple of mail account connected in my phone, same with an account for messages... Someone familiar with the problem??

**Question:** Why does it do well on the Simulator and not on the real device?

Comment: #import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h> works ok for me, I guess you did simple mistake somewhere

Comment: What is the difference between `import MessageUI` in Swift and `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` in Objc?

Comment: I believe no difference for you in your case, did you add MessageUI to build phases?

Comment: Sounds like one of these weird Xcode bugs where fixing requires large amounts of Voodoo. Try to clean the project and delete derived data, restart Xcode and maybe your Mac. -- Did you install one of the Xcode Betas lately? I think I had a similar issue yesterday. Xcode couldn't find UIKit. After I deleted the Beta version that problem was resolved. But this might have been coincidence. Good luck

Comment: @Injectios Strange thing is I can't find the `MessageUI` in the build phases. @Matthias_Bauch Yes I also have the newest Beta installed ... That could be the problem. Let you guys know!

Comment: Still the strange voodoo error @MatthiasBauch . I've tried all of your solutions. Maybe in need to manual install de MessageUI Framework.